# Android - Animate fragment entrance after it's drawn?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using the Support Library and replacing a fragment with a custom slide-in animation.

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.setCustomAnimations(enterIn, enterFragmentOut);
transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, contentFragment);
transaction.commit();
```

The problem I'm experiencing is that the animation starts concurrently with the drawing of the fragment's views, and since the fragment has a rather complex layout (ListViews, &c) the animation is **very** stuttery (only a handful of frames are shown).

I've tried splitting the operation into two parts (with transaction1 = {add_new, hide}, transaction2 = {remove_old, show}) and firing the second transaction after onCreateView() has executed on the new fragment, but I didn't get much improvement at all.

What I'm looking for is a way to start the animation **after the new fragment is fully drawn**, if that's at all possible. Or any other tips that you may have on this issue...

Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you find any solution after 5 years? :)